# Android/Java: UncaughtExceptionHandler and Bugsnag in parallel?

Tags: java, android, exception, error-handling, bugsnag

I'm using *Bugsnag* for **automated error reporting** and would like to perform some additional actions, like a restart, when the app crashes.

**Problem:** both is **working individually**, but not combined. As soon as I add `MyUncaughtExceptionHandler`, *Bugsnag* stops reporting.

**App**

```
public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Bugsnag.init(this);

        // "Breaks" Bugsnag:
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

**MyUncaughtExceptionHandler**

```
public class MyUncaughtExceptionHandler implements
    java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final Class<?> mActivityClass;

    public MyUncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context, Class<?> c) {
        mContext = context;
        mActivityClass = c;
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {
        Bugsnag.notify(exception);
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, mActivityClass);
        mContext.startActivity(intent); // restarts the app

        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I already tried to call `Bugsnag.notify(exception)` within `MyUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spotted your post here but do always reach out to us via Bugsnag support if you want a guaranteed response.

The issue is that when you're calling `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`, you're removing the handler which Bugsnag sets up here:
https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-android/blob/2308eb6c706f66495dea116acf619f695530dff4/sdk/src/main/java/com/bugsnag/android/ExceptionHandler.java#L31

You'd need to call the original handler in order for Bugsnag to detect anything.

Note that killing the process and launching a new intent is not an approach we'd recommend in general in an Android app.

Comment: Thanks, Matt! It worked after moving `Bugsnag.init(this);` under `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...)`.

Comment: *"Note that killing the process and launching a new intent is not an approach we'd recommend in general in an Android app."* ---

I'm restarting the app when it breaks. It's the worst case scenario and I'm trying my best to handle all Exceptions. Do you have an alternative way? Thanks!